# In Java, How to save current state of process, save it to binary file and then execute the that binary to load to memory?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, process

I have been working on AWS Lambda function with some custom Java codes. It's codes had to get long execution time be required but Lambda has execution timeout as 900 seconds of maximum. So I intended that to be saved memory state of process to S3 as file before the timeout and then load that file to be executed from S3 on next execution time.

***How to save all state of process to file and then load to execute that from saved process state?***

Comment: Your question is way too broad. It is like asking "can someone show me how to build a car from scratch". Whole books are written on the subject of serializing application state into files.

Comment: There is no general solution for this requirement.  Java doesn't support application checkpointing.  Of course, it is possible to implement any algorithm in a way that allows a particular computation to be checkpointed.  But you need to implement this yourself ... and there is no general "recipe" for doing this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your JRE won't support such a risky feature but if you're looking to run extraneous tasks I would not suggest saving process states anyway. If you can add some code and details you'll get a more precise solution to your problem, however some basic pointers...

1. Make sure the functions you're processing data with can be dynamically paused and started
2. Write functions to save/load data from a file in any format (json, csv, etc)
3. Write a function to identify when your dp task is complete
4. Hard code a limit to load, process, then write in that order
5. Batch the process in series until you're notified that it's complete

Again this question is really ambiguous so my answer may not be at all what you need. In either case what you want to save is data, not processes. In theory the computer itself is capable of saving the states of all registers, the stack, and program counter in assembly but that's a pretty big no no for a lot of reasons that aren't really part of this discussion

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my ambiguous question to you!

I knew how a application basically save it's data to file and restore that next runtime.
But my work about the question is wrapping Lambda handler to be included ETL migration job application that has to take time over Lambda maximum timeout.

I was already developed Lambda handler building framework being able to include ETL job and deploy the handler to lambda function but I didn't solve that problem of Lambda timeout.

Meanwhile, I thought about like 'jmap' tool. I just guessed that if 'jmap' can dump heap memory, even it could be restored from dumped file.

As collectively thinking, There isn't a way to solve that problem with my guess.
So I could like better to make application data store architecture in ETL job.

Because of ETL job program is built by other ETL solution, I feel some inconvenience.